# Perl Pcap Module not capturing over 1500 Bytes

Tags: perl, pcap

I have a small pcap listener i made in perl. And whenever i get anything over 1500 Bytes, it just prints as 1500.

```
66.0.X.X 1500
```

Now i get that reply when i sent a 2000 byte packet, i also tried sending 1600, and 10k.

No matter what i get 1500 for pcap. 
How can i fix this i looked at SNAPLEN but when i set it under or over, i get the same results.

I have also tried tcpdump and i get weird results, as you can see the first "length" is 1500, but the second a line under is 5000 which is what i sent.

```
tcpdump: listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
21:59:06.142530 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 58, id 45206, offset 0, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    37.X.X.X.48254 > XXX.54: UDP, length 5000
```

my code:

```
use Net::Pcap;
use NetPacket::Ethernet;
use NetPacket::Ethernet qw(:strip);
use NetPacket::IP;
use NetPacket::IP;
use NetPacket::TCP;
use strict;

my $err;

#   Use network device passed in program arguments or if no 
#   argument is passed, determine an appropriate network 
#   device for packet sniffing using the 
#   Net::Pcap::lookupdev method

my $dev = $ARGV[0];
unless (defined $dev) {
    $dev = Net::Pcap::lookupdev(\$err);
    if (defined $err) {
        die 'Unable to determine network device for monitoring - ', $err;
    }
}

#   Look up network address information about network 
#   device using Net::Pcap::lookupnet - This also acts as a 
#   check on bogus network device arguments that may be 
#   passed to the program as an argument

my ($address, $netmask);
if (Net::Pcap::lookupnet($dev, \$address, \$netmask, \$err)) {
    die 'Unable to look up device information for ', $dev, ' - ', $err;
}

#   Create packet capture object on device

my $object;
$object = Net::Pcap::open_live($dev, 65535, 1, 0, \$err);
unless (defined $object) {
    die 'Unable to create packet capture on device ', $dev, ' - ', $err;
}

#   Compile and set packet filter for packet capture 
#   object - For the capture of TCP packets with the SYN 
#   header flag set directed at the external interface of 
#   the local host, the packet filter of '(dst IP) && (tcp
#   [13] & 2 != 0)' is used where IP is the IP address of 
#   the external interface of the machine.  For 
#   illustrative purposes, the IP address of 127.0.0.1 is 
#   used in this example.

my $filter;
Net::Pcap::compile(
    $object, 
    \$filter, 
    '(port 111)', 
    0, 
    $netmask
) && die 'Unable to compile packet capture filter';
Net::Pcap::setfilter($object, $filter) &&
    die 'Unable to set packet capture filter';

#   Set callback function and initiate packet capture loop

Net::Pcap::loop($object, -1, \&process_packet, '') ||
    die 'Unable to perform packet capture';

Net::Pcap::close($object);


    sub process_packet {
    my ($user_data, $hdr, $pkt) = @_;
    my $ip_obj = NetPacket::IP->decode(eth_strip($pkt));
        #print("$ip_obj->{src_ip} -> $ip_obj->{dest_ip} $ip_obj->{caplen}\n");
    warn "packet!\n";
    my %header = %$hdr;
    #process_packet(\%header, $pkt);
    my $len = length $pkt;
    my $fag = length $user_data;
    my $fag2 = length $hdr;
    warn "$header{len} $header{caplen} $len $fag $fag2\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Did you look into either [`Net::Pcap`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Pcap) or [`Net::Pcap::Easy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Pcap-Easy/Easy.pod)?  Where is your code?

Comment: Ah, ok i added my code, totaly forgot about it. and im using Net::Pcap, ill try out Pcap::easy right now.

Comment: oh my god, net::pcap::easy works PERFECT. Thank you miller.

Comment: @user3377106 When you're done getting `Net::Pcap::Easy` to work, please come back and submit it as an answer to this question so other people can benefit from your learning.  Then 2 days later you can select it as the final answer if someone hasn't posted something even more helpful in the mean time.

Answer (score 2):

From "listening on eth1" I infer you're capturing on an Ethernet.  The largest packet size on Ethernet is 1518 bytes (except for non-standard "[jumbo frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame)"), which is:

- 14 bytes of Ethernet header;
- 1500 bytes of Ethernet payload;
- 4 bytes of frame check sequence at the end.

This means that (unless the network is using jumbo frames) the largest IP packet you can send on an Ethernet is 1500 bytes.

So, if you try to send 5000 bytes of data over UDP-over-IPv4 on an Ethernet, that will become a 5008-byte UDP packet when the 8-byte UDP header is added, and that will become a 5028-byte or larger IPv4 packet when the IPv4 header is added (the minimum size of an IPv4 header is 20 bytes, and it can be bigger if there are options in the packet).  That's too big for Ethernet, so the IP layer in the protocol stack on your machine will "[fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation)" that packet into multiple smaller IP packets, and, if all of those fragments arrive at the destination machine, its IP layer will reassemble them into a larger IP packet and then hand the IP payload of the reassembled packet to the UDP layer, so the program receiving the UDP packet will see all 5000 bytes.

Your tcpdump output is the output for the first of the fragments; the IP-layer total length of the packet, extracted from the IP header, is 1500 (IP's length field includes the length of the IP headers and the payload), but the UDP-layer length, extracted from the UDP header (which will normally fit in the first fragment), is 5000.

This has nothing to do with the snapshot length; it has to do with the way IP works, and the maximum packet size on Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Upon advice from the comments, I decided to try [`Net::Pcap::Easy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Pcap-Easy/Easy.pod) instead of [`Net::Pcap`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aPcap).  As stated in the pod for the former module: "*Net::Pcap is awesome, but it's difficult to bootstrap*".

The following code solves my problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Pcap::Easy;

# all arguments to new are optoinal
my $npe = Net::Pcap::Easy->new(
    dev              => "eth1",
    filter           => "port 111",
    packets_per_loop => 10,
    bytes_to_capture => 1024,
    timeout_in_ms    => 0, # 0ms means forever
    promiscuous      => 0, # true or false

        udp_callback => sub {
my ($npe, $ether, $ip, $udp, $header ) = @_;
       print "UDP: $ip->{src_ip}:$udp->{src_port}"
         . " -> $ip->{dest_ip}:$udp->{dest_port} $udp->{len}\n";
},

#    tcp_callback => sub {
#        my ($npe, $ether, $ip, $tcp, $header ) = @_;
#        my $xmit = localtime( $header->{tv_sec} );
# 
#        print "$xmit TCP: $ip->{src_ip}:$tcp->{src_port}"
#         . " -> $ip->{dest_ip}:$tcp->{dest_port}\n";
# 
#    },
# 
#    icmp_callback => sub {
#        my ($npe, $ether, $ip, $icmp, $header ) = @_;
#        my $xmit = localtime( $header->{tv_sec} );
# 
#        print "$xmit ICMP: $ether->{src_mac}:$ip->{src_ip}"
#         . " -> $ether->{dest_mac}:$ip->{dest_ip}\n";
#    },
);

1 while $npe->loop;
```

Comment: This is no good as an answer. You need to explain what you did and why it works.